# After closing programmed application, system handle remains. File unaccessible

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, operating-system

Whenever I start without debugging, close my application and try to compile it again a few seconds later, I get an error:

Error 14: 'Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\xxx.exe" to file "bin\Debug\xxx.exe". Access to the path "bin\Debug\xxx.exe" denied'

Using process explorer I found a handle to my xxx.exe at "System". I also cannot delete the binary. It seems as if the system is still locking the binary for some time after I close my application. Why is that? What can I do about it?

EDIT:
Some new information:

- The problem also occurs with the release version of the program.
- It also occurs, when opened while Visual Studio is closed.
- The handle to the file is directly from the "System" process (PID 4)

Comment: Try disabling the indexing service, sometimes it can cause that kind of problem.

Comment: If it was a web application (or a web application was involved in the debugging session) try `iisreset`

Answer (score 0):

Any program/service that locks your files could be the culprit.  For me its DropBox.  I use iy to sync my whole projects folder and sometimes I have the same problem.  DropBox will lock the file while its syncing.  Its not a huge deal for me biut I would look into any backup type service as the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is your antivirus software. Oftentimes there is a configuration option to exclude certain paths from scanning certain files…